# Can you perform a reaction to somebody else's reaction?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, reactions

Imagine Wizard A tries to cast fireball. Wizard B casts [Counterspell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) as a reaction to try to nullify said fireball.

- Can Wizard C cast counterspell as a reaction to nullify Wizard B's
  counterspell?
- Can you have a group of Wizards of an indefinite population
  counterspelling each other ad nauseam?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can *Counterspell* a *Counterspell*, yes. You're allowed to take reactions on your own turn, and casting *Counterspell* will trigger the reaction for *Counterspell*. This was confirmed in a [Sage Advice column](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/ability-check):

> Can you also cast a reaction spell on your turn? You sure can! Here’s a common way for it to happen: Cornelius the wizard is casting fireball on his turn, and his foe casts counterspell on him. Cornelius has counterspell prepared, so he uses his reaction to cast it and break his foe’s counterspell before it can stop fireball.

There's one important restriction to mention here. If you cast a bonus action spell,

> You can’t cast another spell during the same
>   turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

So you can *Counterspell* the guy trying to *Counterspell* your *Fireball*, but you can't *Counterspell* the guy trying to *Counterspell* your *Expedititous Retreat* (for example).

Comment: That's a really strange caveat about bonus actions spells, but it is on PHB (p.202). I think I might elect to house-rule ignore it unless there is some compelling reason it was put in place.

Comment: @Dumpcats I'm pretty sure it's mostly meant to prevent casting both a bonus action spell and a regular action spell, so houseruling it to allow reaction spells shouldn't break anything.

Comment: just to be sure I've got my head around it, **C** could *Counterspell* B's *Counterspell* to A's *Expeditious Retreat*, right? The failure comes when it's **A**BA, and A's tried to use two bonus-time spells?

Comment: @nitsua60 Yep, it's just A who can't cast another spell that turn.