# Twinned counterspell against multiple reactions

Tags: dnd-5e, targeting, metamagic, reactions, counterspelling

Wizard uses Magic Missiles on two opponents. Both opponents are using the Shield. The sorcerer uses Twinned spell on counterspell to counter the Shield.
Can a sorcerer do that?

I'm not sure if reactions are actually being counted at the same time.

Comment: This might be a duplicate, does it answer your question: [Can you twin Counterspell in response to a Counterspell counter chain?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/94884)

Comment: "to counter the Shield" - Did you mean "to counter both Shields"?

Comment: We've closed this as a duplicate for now, this looks to be fundamentally the same situation as the linked question, just with different reaction spells. If the linked Q&A doesn't resolve your question let us know, and we'll figure out what else is confusing and see about getting this reopened.

Comment: That said, welcome to the stack! Take the [tour] when you have a moment, and if you have a few more moments, peruse the [help] for some more detailed information about stuff works here.

Comment: I think there's some fundamental questions that need to be answered here. Usually attacks are resolved one at a time, so the situation where you have the opportunity to do this won't come up.