# Can a caster Counterspell a Counterspell against a non-cantrip spell they cast?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

If caster A (for example a wizard) casts a spell on their turn, and it is Counterspelled by another caster B, can the original caster Counterspell the first Counterspell?

I am assuming that it is legal to Counterspell a Counterspell if it is done by different individuals, though please correct me if I'm wrong.

I also assume the answer to this question also applies to a caster using their reaction to cast any other non-cantrip spell on their turn, such as casting the Shield spell when taking an opportunity attack when leaving melee, after they have cast another spell with their action.

Comment: Are you asking if its legal to counterspell a counterspell? Because if you are, you should read [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62217/counterspelling-a-counterspell)

Comment: I think I'm really asking if you can cast a non-cantrip spell using your reaction on the same turn you cast another non-cantrip spell using your action?  But this question also covers, can you counterspell a counterspell.  There are a number of posts about casting multiple spells in a turn, but I didn't find a clear explicit answer.

Comment: @Ladifas while the top answer might answer this question, it is not the same question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While the top answer to the question [Can you perform a reaction to somebody else's reaction?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70236/can-you-perform-a-reaction-to-somebody-elses-reaction) answers this question explicitly by quoting the [Sage Advice column](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/ability-check) I feel it is no duplicate, because even while that specific answer might answer this question too, it is not the same question.

Here the quote from the [Sage Advice column](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/ability-check):

> Can you also cast a reaction spell on your turn? You sure can! Here’s a common way for it to happen: Cornelius the wizard is casting fireball on his turn, and his foe casts Counterspell on him. Cornelius has counterspell prepared, so he uses his reaction to cast it and break his foe’s counterspell before it can stop fireball.

This **explicitly** answers this question, but let me additionally explain why/how it works:

*At first, you must be able to cast an additional spell in your round, can you do it?*

You mentioned the rule about not being able to cast another non-cantrip spell after casting certain spells. That is a very confusing rule which can be found in the PHB on p.202.

> **Bonus Action**
>
> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. [...] You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

This means, if the mentioned spell cast by the wizard uses the **bonus action** you can only use cantrips which use your action in your turn. Counterspell does not fulfill these requirements. So, you could not counterspell a counterspell on a bonus action spell cast by yourself.

*Second, can you use your reaction in your own turn?*

On the same page in the PHB it says:

> **Reactions**
>
> If a spell can be cast as a reaction, the spell description tells you exactly when you can do so.

Counterspell tells you:

> 1 reaction, which you take when you see a creature within 60 feet of you casting a spell.

Counterspell itself a spell and if your enemy uses the spell he has to be in 60ft range (unless he uses meta-magic). It does not limit you in any way when the spell you want to counterspell has to be cast, so you can theoretically counterspell in anyones turn, yours too.

Which is supported by PHB p.190:

> **Reactions**
>
> A reaction is an instant response to a trigger of some kind, which can occur on your turn [...]